# JPanel sumindo ao dar um get no mesmo

Tags: java, swing, spring, framework

Estou construindo uma aplicação baseada em camadas utilizando o Spring Framework, sou novato e poço estar fazendo da forma errada.

Meu problema é o seguinte, como pode se ver na imagem abaixo eu tenho o `PrincipalFrame` e o `PessoaFrame` > `PessoaPanel`, eu preciso utilizar o `PessoaPanel` em diversos lugares do sistema pois ele é um modo do usuário buscar qualquer pessoa do sistema, de momento preciso utilizar ele no `PrincipalFrame` e no `PessoaFrame` mas as ações (`Listeners`) estão em `PessoaListaController` e não acho que seja boa pratica declarar tudo novamente no `PrincipalController` pois sera dois lugares para dar manutenção de função para o mesmo objetivo. O problema é que quando eu faço:

`PrincipalFrame.getTabMenuGeral().add("Pessoas", pessoaListaController.getPessoaPanel());`

e depois vou chamar denovo o Panel em outro lugar no sistema, ele acaba ficando invisivel, já tentei os seguintes abaixo:

```
frame.repaint();
frame.getPessoaPanel().visible(true);
```

**Ilustração:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O que é meu PessoaPanel:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de muita busca, acabei chegando na resposta sem querer.

Fiz o seguinte, criei uma classe `PessoaPanelController` e instanciei o `PessoaPanel` nela, chamei o `@PostConstruct` e inicializei todos os botões do `PessoaPanel` e agora quando preciso do `PessoaPanel` eu do um `@Autowired` no meu componente e utilizo, mas a verdadeira resposta era o `@Scope("prototype")` que faz com que cada vez que eu instancio o PessoaPanelController o sistema crie uma nova instancia separada e ninguém compete com ninguém, segue abaixo o meu `Controller`;

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PessoaPanelController extends AbstractController {

@Autowired
public PessoaPanel frame;

@Autowired
private PessoaController pessoaController;

@Autowired
private PessoaService pessoaService;

public PessoaPanelController() { }

@PostConstruct
public void init() {        
/********************************************************************************/
/** Pessoa ToolBar **************************************************************/
/********************************************************************************/
    registerAction(this.frame.getBtnPessoaNovo(), new AbstractAction() {
        protected void action() { frame.showPopupMenuPessoa(); }
    });

    registerAction(this.frame.getPopupMenu().getMnuPessoaNovoFisica(), new AbstractAction() {
        protected void action() { pessoaController.show(); }
    });

    registerAction(this.frame.getBtnPessoaEditar(), new AbstractAction() {
        protected void action() { pessoaEditar(); }
    });

    registerAction(this.frame.getBtnPessoaExcluir(), new AbstractAction() {
        protected void action() { pessoaExcluir(); }
    });

    registerAction(this.frame.getBtnPessoaPesquisar(), new AbstractAction() {
        protected void action() { refreshTablePessoa(); }
    });

    this.frame.getTablePessoa().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {                
            if(event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                pessoaEditar();
            }
        }
    });

    this.frame.getTablePessoa().addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            frame.getBtnPessoaEditar().setEnabled(true);
            frame.getBtnPessoaExcluir().setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}

public void refreshTablePessoa() {  
    this.frame.refreshTablePessoa(this.pessoaService.getAllPessoas());
}

public void pessoaEditar() {
    Pessoa p = frame.getTablePessoa().getPessoaSelected();
    if(p != null) {
        this.pessoaController.show(p);
    }
}

public void pessoaExcluir() {
    Pessoa p = frame.getTablePessoa().getPessoaSelected();

    if(p != null) {
        int opcao = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                "Confirma a exclusão deste(s) registro(s)?",
                "Atenção",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        if(opcao == 0) {
            this.pessoaService.delete(p.getPessoaId());
        }
    }
}

public PessoaPanel getPanel() {
    return frame;
}
```

}